# Error al mostrar posicion de un array con PHP, SQL

Tags: php, sql

Después de hacer una consulta de `id_jugadores` voy guardando su valor en un array `$jugadores` el cual voy a recorrer mediante otra consulta condicionada por un WHERE (donde quiero tratar el array).

Mi error básicamente está al mostrar la posición del array `$jugadores` donde `$i` recorrerá las distintas posiciones del array para poder ser tratados por la consulta sql. En caso de poner el `$jugadores[$i]`, pongo un numero cualquiera, se me ejecuta el código como es debido mostrándome lo deseado.

Los datos del array `$jugadores` puedo llegar a mostrarlos de forma independiente, con lo que el array está correcto.

```html
for($i=1; $i < 10 ; $i++){
      // PRUEBA RECORRIDA ARRAY
      // Consulta muestra valor-posición
      $consultaSQL2 = "SELECT nombre FROM usuario u WHERE u.id_usuario = $jugadores[$i]";
      $sql2 = mysqli_query($enlace, $consultaSQL2);
      if($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
        
        $jug = $fila['nombre'];
        array_push($nombrejug, $jug);
      }
      $i = $i +1;
    }
    print_r($nombrejug);
```

Este sería el error que me aparece:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1
> ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in...

Comment: Me parece que te falta el result_type  if($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2, MYSQL_ASSOC)), prueba con eso.

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error <-- Undefined constant "MYSQL_ASSOC"-->. Sigo pensando que el error esta en la clausula WHERE u.id_usuario = '$jugadores[$i]' (justo en esta parte del array, necesito que me saque el valor de la posición en concreto la cual se irá sumando en cada vuelta)

Comment: $i = $i +1; esa sentencia no es necesaria ya que el ciclo for tiene su propio contador, si pones eso tu variable aumentara una unidad mas por ende , sería como un for de 2 en 2

Comment: Sii, lo tenía en cuenta, era solo una prueba. Finalmente indagando un poco sobre tu consejo, he conseguido resolver el problema de la siguiente forma: "if($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2))".  Ahora, hay alguna forma de incrementar la posición del foreach en un punto determinado del código?. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Espera antes de cualquier cosa , disculpa mi error, era MYSQLI_ASSOC, el MYSQL_ASSOC esta obsoleto

Comment: ¿No debería ser tu ciclo `for($i=1; $i <= count($jugadores) ; $i++){`?

Comment: ¿Has intentado seleccionar la tabla jugadores y unir con usuarios? Algo como `SELECT j.id_jugador, u.nombre FROM id_jugadores j LEFT JOIN usuario u ON u.id_usuario = j.id_jugador`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás poniendo a trabajar a la base de datos más de lo que debería, ya que por cada iteración se abre una conexión a SQL innecesariamente.

Puedes usar alguna de estas opciones:

1- Con condicionales. Si los ID de jugadores estuvieran dentro de un rango, p.ej, 1 al 9:

```
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuario u WHERE u.id_usuario > 0 AND u.id_usuario < 10";
```

2- Con `IN`:

```
<?php
$values = implode(',', range(1, 9)); // genera cadena: '1,2,...9'
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuario u WHERE u.id_usuario IN ($values)";
```

Si los valores del array fueran aleatorios o no consecutivos, entonces puedes usar la 2da forma con todos esos valores.

Finalmente el código quedaría, usando la segunda opción y una sola consulta a la BD:

```
<?php
// $jugadores es un array de ID de jugadores
$nombrejug = array();
$values = implode(',', $jugadores);
$sql = "SELECT nombre FROM usuario u WHERE u.id_usuario IN ($values)";
$result = mysqli_query($enlace, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($nombrejug, $row['nombre']);
}
```

Comment: Finalmente opté por una opción similar y funcionó, pero me gustaria permitir tambien valores vacios al mostrarlos en pantalla sin que salga error

Answer (score 0):

Ya, creo que logré replicar el problema y ya di con la solución, revisa este código y me dices como te fue.

```
$jugadores = array();
$nombrejug = array();

$jugadores[1]=1;
$jugadores[2]=2;
$jugadores[3]=3;
$jugadores[4]=4;
$jugadores[5]=5;
$jugadores[6]=6;
$jugadores[7]=7;
$jugadores[8]=8;
$jugadores[9]=9;
$jugadores[10]=10;

for($i=1; $i <11 ; $i++){
  // PRUEBA RECORRIDA ARRAY
  // Consulta muestra valor-posición
  $consultaSQL2 = "SELECT id_usuario, nombre FROM usuario u WHERE u.idusuario= $jugadores[$i]"; 
  $sql2 = mysqli_query($enlace, $consultaSQL2);
  if($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $jug = $fila['nombre'];

    array_push($nombrejug, $jug);
  }
 // $i = $i +1;
}
print_r($nombrejug);
```